# tns can not create ng app on mac high sierra?

Tags: angular, nativescript, tns

[image: screenshot]

The files in app folder are so weird, what are the tslib.* files? There should be app.component.* and main.ts and something else.

Answer (score 0):

When I reinstalled the nativescript cli, the problem has disappeared.
The reinstall cmd is:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript
npm install nativescript -g
```